# How do I use setX with a file path?

Tags: cmd

I have used setX to store the path to jar.exe (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\jar.exe), but when I use the variable, it tells me that it doesn't recognize 'C:\Program' as an operable program or batch file.

Here is the code I used:

```
setX jar "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\jar.exe"
```

How would I get this to work?

Comment: Put quotes around it when you use it: `"%jar%"`.

Comment: ok...I will try that.

Comment: it works. thank you.